# Ajax requests, long polling or IRC

Tags: mysql, ajax, irc, long-polling

I need to do a live chat system (with multiple user channels, user permissions and must be included in a site and use accounts from that database) so I thought at this solutions: ajax requests at a predefined time like 1 second, long polling or irc.

The advantages and disadvantages would be:

AJAX advantages:

- Easy to implement
- East to check permissions for the site users, give rights, set channels, access everything I need from the database

Disadvantages:

- Inserts lag by default
- Kills the poor server
- Can be used only in the specified page (no outside site client exists)

Long polling:

- Doesn't kill the server
- Less lag
- Can be used only in the specified page (no outside site client exists)
- Harder to implement

IRC:

- Doesn't flood the server
- No lag
- A user can set a client and access chat from outside site
- Don't know how to communicate with my database so I can create channels and give permissions according to my data

Since multiple ajax requests flood the server I can't use that. So between long polling and IRC what do you think it should be better to use?

If is long polling can you please point to a good reference (I used ape - ape-project.org in the past but I was disappointed by its stability)?

If is IRC can you please point me to a reference that shows how to create a connection to my database (mysql) and put the new logged user into a desired channel? For example if in my database I have an entry like name: Gogu, occupation: killer; when Gogu connects I need to put him in the "Killers" channel.